# Rails: AJAX + destroy action in controller not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am currently making an app with users, albums, and photos. I managed to make the AJAX work for the create action when I upload pics, but I can't get AJAX to work for the delete. Instead, it redirects me to an empty show page for the pic. Can anyone give me some guidance?

photos controller:

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:album_id])
  @photo = @album.photos.find(params[:id])
  # @photo.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Photo successfully deleted."
  respond_to do |format|
    if @photo.destroy
      format.js
      # format.json { render json: @photo, status: :created, location: @photo}
      # redirect_to user_album_path(@user, @album)
    end
  end
end
```

destroy.js.erb (I'm supposed to have this right?)

```
$('.destroypicswrapper').remove(".<%= @photo.avatar.url %>");
```

_photodestroy.html.erb partial:

```
<div class="picthumb <%= photo.avatar.url %>">
    <%= link_to image_tag(photo.avatar.url ? photo.avatar.url(:small) : @album.name), root_url %>
    <br>
    <%= link_to "Delete", user_album_photo_path(@user, @album, photo), :remote => true, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure? "} %>
</div>
```

and finally the albums/edit.html.erb page where the delete is initially happening:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit album") %>

<%= render 'form' %>

<div class="destroypicswrapper">
    <% if @album.photos.any? %>
        <%= render :partial => 'photodestroy', :collection => @album.photos, :as => :photo %>
    <% end %> 
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing `:remote => true` for your destroy link.

Comment: thanks gylaz. that fixed my redirect problem, but the divs are still not deleting AJAX-ly.

Comment: Can you describe what you're seeing now?

Comment: when i click the delete button, it gives me the alert "Are you sure?" (as planned), so I click yes, and then no AJAX happens (not as planned). When I refresh, the pic I deleted is deleted (as planned). I think I'm doing the wrong thing in the destroy.js.erb

Comment: I came up with a new strategy for deleting the div with the pic, but it's still not working. check my updated destroy.js.erb and _photodestroy though

Comment: it says error Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .http://s3.amazonaws.com/pholder-edmund/original/40/funny2.jpg?1350077506
[Break On This Error]  

throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

Comment: (i'm storing pics in amazon s3 so that's why the url looks like that.). am I putting the wrong thing in the .remove()? maybe I'm not supposed to be putting in a div class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to render the full url of an image as a class of a div. Also, your Jquery is wrong. Try something like this:

destroy.js.erb

```
$('.destroypicswrapper > #photo_<%= @photo.id %>').remove();
```

Adjust your _photodestroy.html.erb to:

```
<div class="picthumb" id="photo_<%= photo.id %>">
```